# How do I change dokku port settings to a subdomain?

Tags: dokku

I signed up for a VPS server and installed dokku on my Ubuntu server.

I set up dokku with an IP address and a port, but I recently got a domain name, and I want to run dokku as a subdomain.

Is it possible to change from port to subdomain in the settings?
Or is there no other way but to uninstall dokku?

Answer (score 0):

This command should automatically change your app to run on port 80 under new domain:

```
dokku domains:add your-app-name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com
```

Obviously you will need to point your domain's DNS to your VPS IP address. Check out the Dokku docs on their website for how to add SSL / port 443 to your domain.